# How can I populate a spinner with id and value from SQLite database in Kotlin?

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, spinner

I have an SQLite database which has the following columns: id, name, species and origin.
I want to read only the id and name from the database.

```
class AnimalData{
    var id : Int = 0
    var name : String = ""
    var species : String = ""
    var origin : String = ""

    constructor(id: Int, name: String, species: String, origin: String){
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
        this.species = species
        this.origin = origin
        this.note = note
    }

    constructor(id: Int, name :String){
        this.id = id
        this.name = name
    }
}
```

Here is the function from my DataBaseHelper class:

```
fun readIdAndName() : MutableList<AnimalData>{
    var list : MutableList<AnimalData> = ArrayList()

    val db = this.readableDatabase
    val query = "SELECT id, name FROM $TABLE_ANIMAL"
    val result = db.rawQuery(query,null)
    if (result.moveToFirst())
        do{
            var animal = AnimalData()
            animal.id = result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(COL_ID))
            animal.name = result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME))
            list.add(animal)
        }
        while (result.moveToNext())

    result.close()
    db.close()
    return list
}
```

I fill an arraylist with the read data:

```
var animals = arrayListOf<AnimalData>()

val db = DataBaseHandler(this)
    val data = db.readIdAndName()

    data.forEach() {
        animals.add(it)
    }
```

I want to set:

- spinner item id = animal id
- spinner item value = animal name

It is important to do. In case if an animal is deleted from the database, the spinner item wouldn't have the wrong id.

How can I do that? (I want to do operations based on the selected item's id.)

Answer (score 1):

> How can I do that? (I want to do operations based on the selected item's id.)

You will need to use an adapter for the spinner that can handle an AnimalData object.

I would suggest that it's simpler to use the built-in `SimpleCursorAdapter`, which by it's name handles a Cursor.

However, to use a `SimpleCursorAdapter` you **MUST** have an id column named _id (as per `BaseColumns._ID`).

This bypasses the need to create an intermediate array, but requires access to the Cursor and thus that the database is not closed. Opening and closing the database is not a good idea, it is resource hungry.

So first a modified DataBaseHelper :-

```
val DATABASE_NAME = "mydatabase.db"
val DATABASE_VERSION = 1
val TABLE_ANIMAL = "animal";
val COL_ID = "id"
val COL_NAME = "name"
val COL_ORIGIN = "origin"
val COL_SPECIES = "species"

class DataBaseHelper(context: Context): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION) {

    val db = this.writableDatabase //<<<<< ADDED

    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
        /* Create the table and add some data for testing */
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $TABLE_ANIMAL ($COL_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, $COL_NAME TEXT UNIQUE, $COL_SPECIES TEXT, $COL_ORIGIN TEXT)")
        db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO $TABLE_ANIMAL ($COL_NAME,$COL_SPECIES,$COL_ORIGIN) VALUES ('Dog','Canis','Wolf'),('Cat','Felis','Tiger')")
    }

    override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
        TODO("Not yet implemented")
    }
    @SuppressLint("Range")
    fun readIdAndName() : MutableList<AnimalData>{
        var list : MutableList<AnimalData> = ArrayList()

        val query = "SELECT id, name FROM $TABLE_ANIMAL"
        val result = db.rawQuery(query,null)
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            list.add(AnimalData(
                result.getInt(result.getColumnIndex(COL_ID)),
                result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME)),
                result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_SPECIES)),
                result.getString(result.getColumnIndex(COL_ORIGIN))
            ))
        }
        result.close()
        return list
    }
    fun getAnimals(): Cursor {
        /* see above for db */
        return db.query(
            TABLE_ANIMAL, 
            arrayOf(
                "$COL_ID AS ${BaseColumns._ID}", //<<<<< renames the id column to _id
                COL_NAME, 
                COL_SPECIES, // little harm in including species and origin 
                COL_ORIGIN
            ),
            null /* WHERE clause less the WHERE keyword, null = no WHERE clause */,
            null /* arguments to replace ? place holder in the WHERE clause, null if none */,
            null /* GROUP BY clause, null if no GROUP BY clause */,
            null /* HAVING CLAUSE, null if no HAVING clause */,
            COL_NAME + " ASC" /* ORDER BY clause animals will be shown alphabetically a-z*/
        )
    }
}
```

- your `readIdAndName` is defunct and has been replaced by `getAnimals` which returns a cursor that contains all the data with the **id** column as **_id**.

  - note that the convenience method [`query`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#query(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has been used, this builds the underlying SQL (see comments).
- the other important factor is that var `db` has been set so you don not need to include `val db = this.readableDatabase` in all the functions.
- note that their is very little difference between `getReadableDatabase` and `getWritableDatabase`, the former gets a writable database the majority of the time. A read-only database will only be returned if the database cannot be written to.

Next to  the activity, the layout including a Spinner with an id of animal_list.

The entire layout used is :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/hello"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!">
    </TextView>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/animal_list"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/purple_200"
        >
    </Spinner>

</LinearLayout>
```

- purple background so that it jumps out when testing

The activity **MainActivity** has a number of lateinit vars namely:-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var db: DataBaseHelper /* Ready to instantiate an instance of the DataBasehelper */
    lateinit var spinner: Spinner /* Ready to get a Spinner instance */
    var simpleCursorAdapter: SimpleCursorAdapter? = null /* The Adapter for the Spinner. null so the state is known */
    var cursor: Cursor? = null /* The Cursor that will be adapted, null  as it cannot be retreived at this time */
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        db = DataBaseHelper(this) /* get the DatabaseHelper instance */
        spinner = this.findViewById(R.id.animal_list) /* get the spinner instance */
        setOrRefreshSpinner() /* go and set the spinner */

    }

    /*
        This function will setup the spinner if the adapter is null, otherwise it will refresh the spinner by swapping the cursor
        This should be called if the underlying data changes or may have changed
     */
    private fun setOrRefreshSpinner() {
        /* Always get the latest data (Cursor) */
        cursor = db.getAnimals()
        /* Has the Spinner/Adapter been setup, if not then simpleCursorAdapter will be null */
        if (simpleCursorAdapter == null) {
            /* Instantiate the Adapter */
            simpleCursorAdapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, /* a valid context */
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, /* the layout to use (one of android's here), could easily be a custom layout */
                cursor, /* The Cusor that is the source of the drop down list */
                arrayOf(COL_NAME), /* The list of column names from which the data is retrieved */
                intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1), /* The id list, to match the columns to the view in the layout */
                0 /* 0 is fine */
            )
            /* tie the adapter to the spinner */
            spinner.adapter = simpleCursorAdapter
            /* setup the Spinner listeners */
            spinner.onItemSelectedListener = object: AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
                @SuppressLint("Range")
                override fun onItemSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, _id: Long) {
                    /* do not toast when selection is first made (not user selecting by system) */
                    if (view?.context != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            view.context,
                            "You selected ${
                                cursor!!.getString(
                                    cursor!!.getColumnIndex(
                                        COL_NAME
                                    )
                                )
                            } with an id of $_id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                }
                override fun onNothingSelected(p0: AdapterView<*>?) {
                }
            }

        } else {
            /* if refreshing rather than setting up, then tell the adapter about the changed cursor */
            simpleCursorAdapter!!.swapCursor(cursor)
        }
    }

    /* If another activity is started,
        then when the other activity is finished onResume will be called
        so assume that the data may have changed and refresh the spinner
     */
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        setOrRefreshSpinner()
    }

    /* When the activity is destroyed then close the cursor as it will not be used again */
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        if (!cursor!!.isClosed) {
            cursor!!.close()
        }
    }
}
```

**Result**

When started :-

[image]

When Spinner clicked to select :-

[image]

After Selection of Dog :-

[image]